# Anglesharp normalize / fix html

Tags: c#, html, parsing, anglesharp

I have this piece of html

```
<div>
  Outside paragraph
  <p>In paragraph</p>
</div>
```

As you can see there's `Outside paragraph` piece of text which, being outside paragraph, is not wanted situation.

Is there any AngleSharp method (if not Anglesharp then any other) which would allow me to *normalize / fix* this piece of html so it looks like:

```
<div>
  <p>Outside paragraph</p>
  <p>In paragraph</p>
</div>
```

So, a piece of code which will put `Outside paragraph` in to paragraph

Comment: Florian, one of the authors of AngleSharp, is hell of an awesome supporter. Why not [open an issue](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/new) on the AngleSharp GitHub repository?

Comment: Thanks Uwe - much appreciated! Indeed I am not very active in looking at SO, but I'm glad you pointed him to GH where I have set up all kinds of notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngleSharp does not provide such custom logic, but gives you mean to roll out your own normalization schemes.

In the following example I use the `TreeWalker` to simplify iterating over only text nodes.

The code looks for the given conditions to insert the paragraph dynamically.

```
var context = BrowsingContext.New();
var document = await context.OpenAsync(res => res.Content("foo<div>Outside<p>Inside</p></div>bar"));
var walker = document.CreateTreeWalker(document.Body, AngleSharp.Dom.FilterSettings.Text);

while (walker.ToNext() != null)
{
    var current = walker.Current;

    // if just whitespace, e.g., formatting line breaks, or in p anyway - skip
    if (
        (current.TextContent.Trim().Length == 0) ||
        (current.ParentElement.LocalName == "p"))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // if next to paragraph perform the normalization
    else if (
        (current.PreviousSibling is IElement previous && previous.LocalName == "p") ||
        (current.NextSibling is IElement next && next.LocalName == "p"))
    {
        var newNode = document.CreateElement("p");
        current.ReplaceWith(newNode);
        newNode.Append(current);
    }
}

document.Body.ToHtml().Dump();
```

The dumped result looks as follows:

```
<body>foo<div><p>Outside</p><p>Inside</p></div>bar</body>
```

This is potentially not *everything* what you need, but should give you the pointer in the right direction.

*Note*: You can also roll your own (recursive) iteration or use, e.g., a custom `IMarkupFormatter` to make the normalization as serialization. There are multiple ways. The given one changes the DOM - as such further operations (not just serialization) may be possible.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome support, Florian 